# Can "densely ordered dimensions" make sense?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Here's the motivation behind this question:

Let's note $E = \mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space equipped with the norm $\lVert . \rVert_2$, and with an orthonormal basis $B$ of cardinality $\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$. There is a bijection $f$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$.

Equipped with the norm $\lVert . \rVert_2$, the function $f$ is not continuous, since all elements of $f[\mathbb{R}]$ are $\sqrt{2}$ appart.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to equip $E$ with a different metric (not necessarily induced by a norm) so that $f$ is made continuous?
2. If the answer to 1. is "no", are there any interesting (I know it's arbitrary) non-trivial topologies that could make $f$ continuous?

I feel like the answer to 1. *no*, but my math skills are way too rusty to actually answer this interrogation of mine. I *feel* like having such a metric $d$ would be sort of like ordering $B$ with a dense order and making "close" elements of $B$ contribute less to the distance of an element $x \in E$ to $0$, hence the title of the question, but I can't tell much more than that.

Comment: Yes, you can always take the discrete metric. Of course that's not likely to be very interesting. What do you want such a thing for?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think about that, I wanted to exclude it from question 2 but forgot it answered question 1. The only reason is curiosity, about the existence (or lack thereof) of  a continuous path that only goes through a given dimension in one point, while keeping the metric used for that "as natural as possible". Obviously that last point is arbitrary and up to interpretation, and possible answers would vary depending on how removed from the euclidean norm we allow our metric to be. (It's to know whether I can/want to incorporate concepts using such an idea in a scifi setting.)

Comment: Can you say more precisely what you mean by "only goes through a given dimension in one point"?

Comment: It was meant to say that for any given element $e \in B$ there is at most $1$ real number $x$ such that $f(x)$ has a non-zero scalar factor in front of $e$ if written as a linear combination of elements of $B$. Hence "forcing $f$ to continuously change dimensions".